# issue in cakephp pagination

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

i am getting data based on category using this code

```
$this->paginate=$this->Project->find('all', array('conditions' => array('category' => $this->request->data['Project']['category'])));
        $this->set('projects', $this->paginate);
```

by using above code i am getting these errors

```
Warning (2): array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given [CORE\Cake\View\Helper\PaginatorHelper.php, line 403]
Warning (2): array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array [CORE\Cake\View\Helper\PaginatorHelper.php, line 403]
```

how i can resolve this isse?

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html (!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong.

Use:

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array('conditions' => array('Project.category' => $this->request->data['Project']['category']));
$this->set('projects', $this->Paginator->paginate());
```